# In my MVC app, why is the performance so slow after adding this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

Is there any way to have this same idea, which is to set the day back one day on these values without causing a huge impact on search times?
Without this block of code it loads a new page in under a second.  After adding it, the time between page loads goes to 6-7 seconds.

```
//incidents is an IQueryable

//Set date backwards one day if incident is entered during third shift after midnight
        for (var x = 0; x < incidents.Count(); x++){
            DateTime createdDate = incidents.ToList().ElementAt(x).DateCreated;
            TimeSpan createdTime = createdDate.TimeOfDay;
            if (createdTime > startTime && createdTime < endTime){
                incidents.Skip(x).First().DateCreated = new DateTime(2019,01,01);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `incidents` is an `IQueryable`, you are executing a database call *`2x+1` times*. Once for `Count`, plus once for `ToList` and once for `Skip(x).First` *on each incident*.

You could try calling `ToList()` *before* the loop and processing the hydrated list to see if performance improves.

Answer (score 3):

It likely has something to do with the many `.ToList()`, `.Skip()` and `.Count()` calls. 
Try the following instead:

```
foreach (var incident in incidents.ToList())
{
    var createdDate = incident.DateCreated;
    var createdTime = createdDate.TimeOfDay;
    var index = incidents.IndexOf(indcident);
    if (createdTime > startTime && createdTime < endTime){
        incidents.Skip(index).First().DateCreated = new DateTime(2019,01,01);
    }
}
```

And, I'm not very familiar with `.Skip()`, but could you not simplify the code to this?

```
foreach (var incident in incidents.ToList())
{
    var createdDate = incident.DateCreated;
    var createdTime = createdDate.TimeOfDay;
    if (createdTime > startTime && createdTime < endTime){
        incident.DateCreated = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using .skip().first() because I was running into errors with LINQ, and it was suggested on a post that I had looked at to use it instead of what I was using previously.  I thought it was an odd syntax to use, but it worked for me.

Comment: @sjohn285 As I understand, `.Skip(x)` will take your array/list/enumerable, and skip `x` elements into the array. Then you're calling `.First()` which takes the element at that array, and then you are updating the `.DateCreated` field on that element.  
  You should be able to achieve the same effect with my second suggested code (as well as improve readability/maintainability).